# Pasar fecha de un input a otro en AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hola chicos lo que quiero hacer es recoger la fecha que pongo en uno de los inputs vease:
create.html

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="fechaInicio">Fecha de la cita:</label>
        <div class="input-group date fecha">
    <input type="text" name="fechaInicio" class="form-control" id="fechaInicio" ng-model="cita.fechaInicio"><span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></i></span>
</div>
```

Pasarlo al controlador:
controllers.js

```
$scope.getHoras = function(){
        var fechaInicio = fechaInicio;
        $http.get('../api/horas.php'),{'fechaInicio':fechaInicio}.then(function(response){
            $scope.citas = response.data;
        });
    };
```

hacer la consulta:
horas.php

```
<?php
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
@session_start();
$id = $_SESSION["user_id"];
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "root";
$dbname = "pruebas";
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
/*$sql = "SELECT hora FROM horas where $fecha and horaCompleta = '1'"*/
$sql = "SELECT hora FROM citas WHERE horaCompleta = 0 AND 'fechaInicio = $date-> fechaInicio' ";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
     $data = array() ;
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $data[] = $row;

    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
echo json_encode($data);
$conn->close();
?>
```

y ahora visualizar los datos recogidos en el create.html:

```
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="hora" ng-init="getHoras()">Hora:</label>
<select ng-model="cita.hora">

<option
value="{{cita.hora}}"
ng-repeat="cita in citas">
{{cita.hora}}
</option>
</select>
```

Si le quito esta parte ,{'fechaInicio':fechaInicio} en controllers.js y hago la consulta solo en horas disponibles si me las visualiza pero yo necesito que tome de referencia la fecha que selecciono arriba. Gracias por la ayuda!

EDITO: Agrego foto de lo que quiero conseguir:
[image: captura1]

Bien lo que pretendo es que cuando alguien selecione una fecha me visualice todas las fechas "vacias" o todas las fechas ocupadas.

Comment: A ver si entendi tu pregunta. El modelo cita.fechaInicio no se esta actulizando en el controlador?

Comment: basicamente que le intento pasar el dato fechaInicio a la consulta para que me filtre los horarios pero no lo hace, y supongo que es porque no paso bien el dato pero no veo donde fallo!

Answer (score 1):

Aquí:

```
$scope.getHoras = function(){
        var fechaInicio = fechaInicio;
        $http.get('../api/horas.php'),{'fechaInicio':fechaInicio}.then(function(response){
            $scope.citas = response.data;
        });
    };
```

Te está faltando la referencia con la vista de fechaInicio.
Tal vez quieres decir lo siguiente:

```
$scope.getHoras = function(){
        var fechaInicio = $scope.fechaInicio; 
        //o vm.fechaInicio, según tengas referenciada el view model
        $http.get('../api/horas.php'),{'fechaInicio':fechaInicio}.then(function(response){
            $scope.citas = response.data;
        });
    };
```

Comment: Listo, te las convertí en comentarios. Un saludo

Comment: Hola Cynth he probado la solución que propones pero no funciona, voy a adjuntar una foto e intentar explicar un poco mas que es lo que intento.

Comment: el error que tienes es como se llama tu campo de fecha se llama cita.fechaInicio @Cynth cambia el campo de fecha inicio y deberia de funcionarte

Comment: cita.fechaInicio, el cita. me imagino que es cómo ha referenciado al componente, por lo que la manera de llamar un view model en la vista sería esta. 
De todas maneras, falta información ya que no sabemos a ciencia cierta si mi suposición es correcta o no.

Comment: @CynthS.B.@JackNavaRow Decidme que informacion os puedo adjuntar o necesitais para ayudarme es para un trabajo de la univesidad y  llevo como 1 mes y no puedo sacarlo hacia delante.

Comment: Tendría que ver cómo estás generando el componente o directiva, sobretodo cómo has llamado al "controller" o cómo has denominado el "controllerAs". Por otro lado saber si estás usando siempre $scope o si estás usando el famoso un view model (ej: vm = this; vm.variableParaVista).